# Whois node bulk domains

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get the email from a array of domains using a whois node module,  but I'm always getting the same error >> "site is not defined".
The code Works fine for a single domain, but not for a list. Can anyone help-me on this matter? Thank you in advance:

```js
var whois = require("whois-json");

arr = [
"google.com",
"example.com"
]

function getWhois(site) {
  whois(site, function(err, result){
      var output = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
      output = JSON.parse(output);
      email = output['email'].replace(' ', ',').toString().split(",");
      console.log(email[0]);
  })
}

arr.forEach(function(i) {
  getWhois(site);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```
arr.forEach(function(i) {
   getWhois(site); // site is not defined here
});
```

You have not defined "site". You probably meant to do `getWhois(i);`